# ParserError while reading file with read_csv

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to read file using pandas read_csv:
data=pd.read_csv(fileName)

I get an error message:

> ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Calling read(nbytes) on
>   source failed. Try engine='python'

When I try

```
data=pd.read_csv(fileName,encoding='utf8',engine='python')
```

I get the message:
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied.

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: DO your file have read permission?

Comment: You need to give us more information to work with. Can you edit the question to include a small sample of the data if you think it could assist with identifying where the parsing error initially occurs? You also definitely want to check that the file permissions are as you'd expect them to be as @py-D is starting to say.

Comment: Open the file in notepad and click save as. At the bottom it will show you the encoding of the file. Make sure that it is indeed UTF-8 and not ANSI.